# Push Notification with Status bar in Mobilefirst 7.1

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing push notification & Tag notification in Mobilefirst 7.1 application by following the document and sample which are located at

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/

All things are fine except one. I get a notification badge in status bar in android, when application is close or in background.

If I open application by clicking that badge or I open application by clicking app icon (Without touching that badge), In both the case, Payload receiver function is getting called and I am getting Payload. And also that badge is getting hide.

What I want is, Identify the difference between these two scenario that application is opened from app icon or badge of status bar.

Is there any way to do this in mobilefirst?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to accomplish the requirement using IBM MobileFirst SDK. You will need to try out pure native Android APIs ( if available) to achieve what you are asking.